# Is there a way to detect mouse press in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to a link when it is clicked, but I can't use:

```
$('a.someLink').click(function() {
   // code
});
```

since click seems to detect when a user clicks and lets go of the mouse clicker on an element. I need to add the class as soon as the user has clicked on the element, even before he lets ago of the mouse clicker and after he lets go I need the class to be removed.

Basically I'm trying to mimic css's active state on links:

```
a:active
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[mousedown()](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) would be what you are looking for in the jQuery docs

Comment: remember to do a `return false;` at the end of your event function definition or else your link click event will be sent to the browser and you could navigate away from the page after executing your event javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$('a.someLink').mousedown(function() { //code });` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.someLink').mousedown(function() {
 //code
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Answer (score 1):

With `$('a.someLink').mousedown()` you can add the class, and then with `$('a.someLink').mouseup()` you can remove it.

- mousedow(): http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/
- mouseup(): http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/

Answer (score 0):

Try `mousedown` which is triggered even before `click` event.

```
$('a.someLink').mousedown(function() {
   // code
});
```